# How to move operation controls/gizmo to screen?

Tags: modeling

Editing a large: Object or part of Object;. And need to perform a change such so some part of the edited assets in result would be located closely to certain coordinates .

When zooming-in to the targeted coordinates (to perform a more precise change), the gizmos go out the screen . How to temporally get them on-screen ?

I saw [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147162/how-to-script-a-gizmo-that-would-be-transformablemove-rotate-scale-independa), but is there any existing or plug-and-play way to perform such changes ?

Comment: You can press G with an object selected to Grab it. It doesn't even need to be on screen. Press X/Y/Z to lock the movement to an axis. For long distance moving, its probably better to move the 3D cursor with Shift+RightClick then Object > Snap > Object to Cursor (Or Shift+S then 8).

Comment: @Benus this won't work for actions other than "Move", "Rotate" and "Scale" .